# Difference between 2 jquery codes

Tags: javascript, jquery

So, anyone knows what the difference between this:

```
$(document).on("click", "sometag", function () {

});
```

and:

```
$("sometag").on("click", function () {

});
```

??

Comment: 1st one is for [delegating an event](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) and the 2nd one is normal event handling!

Comment: I recommend to read the **jQuery documentation**: https://api.jquery.com/on/ . Is there anything in there that you don't understand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First one is **[event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)**

Event delegation allows us to attach a single event listener, to a parent element, that will fire for all descendants matching a selector, whether those descendants exist now or are added in the future.

```
$(document).on("click", "sometag", function () {

});
```

**normal click** :Attach an event handler function for one or more events to the selected elements.

```
$("sometag").on("click", function () {

});
```

Sample Code

HTML

```
<buton>on normal click
    </button>
```

**JS**

```
$("button").on("click", function () {  // it does not work dynamically created element,only static (when dom is loaded )

    $("body").append("<div>delegatin</div>");
    alert("normal");
});

$("body").on("click", "div", function () { // it will work dynamically created dom 
    alert("delegation");
});
```

**

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/dro3knq3/3/)

**

Answer (score 0):

The second one in your code is called delegate event handler.

On a data table with 1,000 rows in its tbody, this example attaches a handler to 1,000 elements:

```
$( "#dataTable tbody tr" ).on( "click", function() {
alert( $( this ).text() );
});
```

A delegated-events approach attaches an event handler to only one element, the tbody, and the event only needs to bubble up one level (from the clicked tr to tbody):

```
$( "#dataTable tbody" ).on( "click", "tr", function() {
alert( $( this ).text() );
});
```

You can read more [here](http://api.jquery.com/on/)